# Properly typing the MongoDB find method in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, mongodb

I'm working on a TypeScript project that involves MongoDB, and I'm facing challenges with correctly typing the `find` method of MongoDB. Below is the code snippet I'm working with:

```js
import { ReitsType } from '@/app/api/types/reits';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { db } from '../mongo';
import { ActionsType } from '../types/actions';

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
    console.log(req);
    const sortKey: keyof ReitsType | keyof ActionsType =
        'averageDy5YearsRanking';
    try {
        const collection = db.collection('reits');
        const documents = await collection
            .find<ReitsType | ActionsType>({
                averageDy5YearsRanking: { $gte: 5 }
            })
            .sort({ [sortKey]: 1 })
            .toArray();
        return NextResponse.json(documents);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while fetching data:', error);
        return NextResponse.error();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm unable to define the correct type for the document that will be returned by the find method. The ReitsType and AtionsType interfaces represent the possible types, but it seems that the typing used is not being recognized properly by TypeScript.

I would like to understand how I can properly type the find method so that TypeScript recognizes the returned document type and provides me with appropriate code support, such as autocompletion of properties and identification of possible type errors.

Correct type find method with mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// you have to add the type here 
const collection = db.collection<ReitsType>('reits');
```

then when you write:

```
 const documents = await collection.find()
```

typescript will automatically infer the types for `documents` and it will auto complete. if you write

```
const documents = await collection.find().sort(whileCursorHere)
```

click on `CTRL + SPACE`, you will see the options

[image]

But if you need to specify the keys of sorting

```
 const documents = await collection.find().sort({key:1})
```

Once you click on `CTRL+SPACE`, while cursor is in `sort({whileCursorHere})`, you might expect to see the keys of your type, in your example MyData,

```
interface MyData {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  adress: string;
}
```

you might want to see auto completion for `name`, `age` or `address` but you do not because this is the type fort `sort` method

```
sort(sort: Sort, direction?: SortDirection | undefined): FindCursor<WithId<MyData>>
```

and type of `Sort` does not except a generic

```
export declare type Sort = string | Exclude<SortDirection, {
    $meta: string;
}> | string[] | {
    [key: string]: SortDirection;
} | Map<string, SortDirection> | [string, SortDirection][] | [string, SortDirection];
```

Comment: thank you, your solution correct for 'find' but not for 'sort'
[find working](https://i.imgur.com/w0T24md.png)
[sort not working](https://i.imgur.com/BPZgitx.png)

and another question about if I have find options separate than my find

Comment: What error r u getting? It should infer sort, too

Comment: Not erros, just not auto complete

Comment: can you create a repo or share the repo

Comment: [there is](https://github.com/collaxd/tests-mongo---ts/blob/main/app.ts)

Comment: it does autocomplete. i updated the answer

Comment: I thought I would complete something like the 'keys' of my object but it's more than enough so, I appreciate your time

Comment: I appreciate your 25 :) also if you are sure your project works fine,  give me the reputation bounty, too :)